# AWK, поменять местами слова в строке

Tags: awk

Как поменять местами чётные и нечётные слова строке?
Только начал изучать awk.

```
for(i = 1; i <= length(string); i++){
        if(string[i] == " "){
            if(count == 1){ 
                count = 2;              
            }
            else{
                count = 1;
                temp1 = ""; j = 0;
                temp2 = ""; k = 0;
                printf("%s %s", temp2, temp1);      
            }   
        }
        else{
            if(count == 1){
                temp1[j] == string[i];
                j = j + 1;      
            }
            if(count == 2){
                temp2[k] == string[i];
                k = k + 1;      
            }
        }
    }
```

Это не работает, выдает ошибку: illegal reference to variable string.

Comment: Вы уверены, что это надо сделать *в переменной,* а не *в файле*?  *AWK* прежде всего предназначен именно для работы с файлами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

главная допущенная ошибка — это попытка сделать посимвольный разбор строки, что чрезмерно усложняет реализацию. ведь программа *awk* сама отлично справляется с разбивкой строки на слова.

воспользовавшись этим её свойством, можно сделать, например, так:

```
{
  s = $0 # на случай, если в строке ноль или одно слово, берём всю строку

  if (NF > 1) { # если количество слов больше одного

    s = $2" "$1 # начинаем с перестановки первого и второго слов

    # цикл с третьего по последнее чётное слово с шагом два
    for (n = 3; n <= (NF - NF % 2); n += 2) {
      s = s" "$(n + 1)" "$n # добавляем два очередных слова
    }

    if (NF % 2 == 1) { # если количество слов нечётное
      s = s" "$NF      # добавляем последнее
    }
  }

  # печатаем результат
  print s
}
```

пример входного файла:

```
раз два три четыре пять шесть семь
восемь девять десять одиннадцать двенадцать тринадцать

четырнадцать
пятнадцать шестнадцать
семнадцать восемнадцать девятнадцать
```

результат его обработки:

```
два раз четыре три шесть пять семь
девять восемь одиннадцать десять тринадцать двенадцать

четырнадцать
шестнадцать пятнадцать
восемнадцать семнадцать девятнадцать
```